# Getting an Image (Stream Data) from the ArDrone 2.0, using opencv2 or opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, ar.drone

I want to get an image (Stream Data) from the ArDrone, using opencv2 or opencv.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cv::Mat image;

    if (!cap.open("tcp://192.168.1.1:5555"))
    {
        printf("AR.Drone ERROR CONNECT\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> image;

        if (!image.empty())
        {
            cv::imshow("AR.Drone", image);
            cout << "OK" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
            cv::waitKey(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always 'OK' but sometimes 'Overflow', 'Out of range' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve just discovered that great solution which mixes AR Drone 2 and OpenCV.
It may help to have a look to it : 
https://github.com/puku0x/cvdrone

Answer (score 0):

The AR.Drone uses a non-standard video format that many libraries and applications cannot handle.  For best results, you will need to decode the video as sent by the drone, which is H264 video combined with the drone's custom PaVE headers.  For more information, see other posts, such as [Ardrone Video Stream decoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507134/ardrone-video-stream-decoding-in-android)